# return vue data values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm using VUE (and I'm new to it) to create elements based on the data and updating their content based on `v-model` inputs. I'll put the example code below however what I'm trying to do is use some jQuery/JS to allow the user to adjust the font sizes in each created element with sliders.

I have code that works but I'm creating a function for every slider and linking it up to text in each created component (6 functions all together, as there's two sliders for each of the 3 content being created). I feel like I could get the script down to two functions if I could append/prepend the `name` data used in the data() to the class names being targeted in the function.

Currently I have:

```js
// Vue data

  const bannerApp = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        imgSrc: "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/portrait-passport-identity-card-id-driver-licence-to-pretty-woman-134331061.jpg",
        yourName: "Enter Name",
        jobTitle: "Enter Job Title",
        banners: [
          {
            name: "portrait",
            bwidth: 200,
            bheight: 300,
            fontSize1: 10,
          },
          {
            name: "landscape",
            bwidth: 300,
            bheight: 200,
            fontSize1: 12,
          },
          {
            name: "square",
            bwidth: 300,
            bheight: 300,
            fontSize1: 14,
          },
        ],
      };
    },
  }).mount("#BannerApp");
  
// font sliders

  $(".slider1-portrait").on("input", function () {
    $(".portrait-name").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
  });

  $(".slider2-portrait").on("input", function () {
    $(".portrait-title").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
  });

  $(".slider1-landscape").on("input", function () {
    $(".landscape-name").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
  });

  $(".slider2-landscape").on("input", function () {
    $(".landscape-title").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
  });

  $(".slider1-square").on("input", function () {
    $(".square-name").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
  });

  $(".slider2-square").on("input", function () {
    $(".square-title").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
  });
```

```css
#BannerApp {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.banCont {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.banCont > p {
    margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.banCont > h3 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.banCont input {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.banInner {
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 90%;
}

input {
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
}

img {
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.portrait, .square {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.banInner.landscape {
    aspect-ratio: 200/300;
    height: auto !important;
}

.banInner.landscape {
    aspect-ratio: 300/200;
    height: auto !important;
}

.banInner.square {
    aspect-ratio: 500/500;
    height: auto !important;
}

.landscape {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: end;
}

.content h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.content h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.36/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="BannerApp">
  <div
      v-for="(banner, bannerKey) in banners"
      :key="bannerKey"
      :class="'banCont'"                    
  >
      <h3>{{banner.name}} version</h3>
      <p>Name Size:</p>
      <input :class="'slider1-' + banner.name" type="range" min="10" max="50" value="0" step="1">
      <p>Title Size:</p>
      <input :class="'slider2-' + banner.name" type="range" min="10" max="50" value="0" step="1">

      <div :class="'banInner ' + banner.name" :style="{ width: banner.bwidth+'px', height: banner.bheight+'px' }">                        
          <img :src="this.imgSrc" />
          <div class="content">
              <h2 :class="banner.name + '-name'">{{yourName}}</h2>
              <h3 :class="banner.name + '-title'">{{jobTitle}}</h3>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

*I've not included all the `v-model` fields or anything to customise it, just enough to show the font slider examples*

As you can see (hopefully) it works, however if I could update the bottom input functions to include the `name` data() value from the VUE data() something like this:

`$("'.slider1-' + banners.name").on("input", function () { $("banners.name + '-name'").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px"); });`

and

`$(".slider2-' + banners.name").on("input", function () { $("banners.name + 'title'").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px"); });`

In my head that would mean I only need two instead of the 6 functions creating. The problem is that doesn't work in the jQuery currently like it does in the html to create the class names, so can you add VUE data() values to JS functions like I'm expecting? and how?

Also if someone has a better way of doing it, by all means fire away, I just know it can be more efficient.

Comment: Not directly answering this question: This should be possible to do in pure VueJS. I suggest reading up a bit more on it. Especially https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html

Comment: Thank you Puelo, yours and yoduh's help has allowed me to learn this concept and adapt it for my app thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment that you should do this with *just* Vue.js.  You should always leave Vue to manage the DOM for you. Vue manages a Virtual DOM, running render functions and comparing VNodes in order to update the actual DOM in the most efficient way possible. Directly accessing and changing the DOM via JS/JQuery is not good practice and can intefere with Vue's management.

For your problem, you will want to use [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#form-input-bindings) to create a two-way binding between your input elements and some data variables that will hold the font size values, and [inline style binding](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-inline-styles) to dynamically update the font size of your texts.

First is to add the data variables that will hold your font size values. Add a name font size and title font size variable to each banner object:

```js
{
  name: "portrait",
  bwidth: 200,
  bheight: 300,
  nameSize: 16, // default font size
  titleSize: 12, // default font size
},
```

Next, add `v-model` to each input, binding the appropriate variable. In your case you also need to remove the `value` attribute, since v-model is taking care of setting that for you:

```html
<p>Name Size:</p>
<input v-model="banner.nameSize" :class="'slider1-' + banner.name" type="range" min="10" max="50" step="1">
<p>Title Size:</p>
<input v-model="banner.titleSize" :class="'slider2-' + banner.name" type="range" min="10" max="50" step="1">
```

Finally, add the inline style binding to your h2 and h3 elements:

```html
<h2 :class="banner.name + '-name'" :style="{fontSize: banner.nameSize + 'px'}">{{yourName}}</h2>
<h3 :class="banner.name + '-title'" :style="{fontSize: banner.titleSize + 'px'}">{{jobTitle}}</h3>
```

[Vue SFC Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Amazing thank you, I forgot to add a comment back the other day after trying and adapting this to my app. As I said I'm still new to Vue so this is a new concept for me and I just made it work with other coding knowledge, however this both works and optimises the code a lot thank you.